# Connecting to Website with a Login/Cookie via a Proxy in Perl

Tags: perl, cookies, https, proxy

I wrote the following script in perl to connect to a website using a proxy.  Granted the proxy address might not be functional at this instant, but conditional on the proxy address yielding no problems, the code works fine.

I am wondering how I may extend it to a website in which there is a cookie and in which I must provide a login.  That is, in the code, I would like to use: $mech->submit_form().  My problem is not how to code the $mech stuff for the cookie and login (I have successfully done that), but rather, how can I do this via a proxy address.  I ask, in part, because I am not even sure how to do this in a web browser.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use utf8;
 use WWW::Mechanize;
 use WWW::Mechanize::Link;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
 use Data::Dumper;

 BEGIN { $| = 1 }
 $ENV{'HTTP_PROXY'} = 'http://66.35.68.145:7808';
 $ENV{'HTTPS_PROXY'} = 'http://66.35.68.145:7808';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $response = $mech->get("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
print Dumper($response->decoded_content);
```

Comment: Have you read the [perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)? That's where I would start.

Comment: I have read that perldoc and I love how well it is written.  My problem is not with how to code the $mech stuff per se.  As I said, I have already coded it to work without the proxy.  I am not sure how to incorporate the proxy per that script that I wrote.  And part of my problem is that I don't know how to do this in a browser either.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using [WWW::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.15/lib/WWW/Curl.pm)